# php Variable for blocking certain URLS

Tags: php

I am writing a function in php for blocking some urls like Scam & Fraud or profanity. It should be act like a filter or validation rule. I am just confusing which variable is best for this purpose.

```
1. trim()
2. strippos ()
```

or do you have any better solutions then this .?

Function would be like this

```
function validation($data) {
$data = trim(https://www.url.com, https://www.url1.com ...);
return data;
}
```

OR

```
 function validation($data) {
    $data = stripos(https://www.url.com, https://www.url1.com ...);
    return data;
    }
```

Comment: Have you read any of the documentation about those functions? Neither is very apropos here.

Comment: Well for starters that's not how trim() works.

Comment: [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) and [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) are **not** variables, they are general-purpose [string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php).

Comment: can you propose any better solutions for match the string .? There are more than 1000 links I know this can be done by if and else statement but how to match the string. trim function strip whitespaces and stripos position the substring in a string . If i use str_replace thebn it would be too long for writing every string and replace with some other data..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That ain't gonna work. I'd list all the url's you want to check in an array and search in there;

```
function is_url_allowed($url) {
    $not_allowed = array(
        'google.com',
        'facebook.com',
        'usa.gov'
    );
    $parsed_url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    return !in_array($parsed_url, $not_allowed);
}
```

Comment: I did not see that  I am not a pro like you guys. Thanks so much.

Comment: hey, no-one is, until he is :p every one of us started with a `<?php echo 'hello world'; ?>`, and none of us is ever done learning. so never be ashamed of asking (we all still do). Or like our old friend Confucios once said; There's no such thing as a stupid question, there are only stupid answers.

Comment: Thats very nice of you to say .. Thanks